# What parameter include in the parenthesis of JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

Since I am into the basics of JavaScript I am able to create array, but I want to know what we might include in the parenthesis of array like test=new Array("parameter?"); so I meant what to include as parameter of that javascript array

Comment: Are you wanting to create an array with some existing items as the initial contents?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949162/how-does-parentheses-work-in-arrays-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you find yourself writing `new Array`, there's probably a better way to do it. But first I'll explain the `Array` constructor and then talk about better ways.

The `Array` constructor has two forms: A form that takes zero or one arguments (*if* that one argument is a number), and a form that takes more than one argument (or just one argument if the argument is not a number). Never use the second form, and avoid using the first one.

The first form:

```
var a = new Array(5);
```

...creates an array with a `length` of `5` which has no entries (JavaScript arrays are "sparse," because they're not really arrays at all — more on that below). If you don't supply any argument at all, the `length` is `0`.

The second form:

```
var a = new Array(5, 6);
```

...creates an array with as many entries as there are arguments (so, two in this case) and uses the arguments to set the values of those entries.

Note that both the number *and type* of arguments is important:

```
var a = new Array(5);   // Creates an array with length = 5 with no entries
var b = new Array("5"); // Creates an array with length = 1 and entry [0] = "5"
```

It's almost always **much** better to use array literals.

The first form above, done with an array literal instead:

```
var a = [];
a.length = 5;
```

The second form above, done with an array literal instead:

```
var a = [5, 6];
```

Using array literals is "better" (in my view) for several reasons, some of which are more subjective than others:

1. It's clearer, and doesn't have the ambiguity that the `Array` constructor has. For instance, what does this do?

   ```
   var a = new Array(foo);
   ```

   Answer: *It depends* (on what `foo` has it in it, a number or something else). This is just Not Good<sup>tm</sup>.
2. It's not susceptible to someone overwriting the `Array` symbol (which they can do) with something else.
3. It's more concise and expressive (this is probably the most subjective of the reasons).

More reading:

- [The ECMAScript (JavaScript) specification on `Array`s](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)
- *[A myth of arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)* (in my blog), which explains how JavaScript arrays aren't arrays

Comment: Thank you for descriptive answer.

Answer (score 3):

The array constructor is overloaded and which result you get depends on how many arguments you pass and of which data type they are:

- **More than one argument** (any type):

  ```
  var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4);
  ```

  Creates a new array containing the values passed to the constructor.
- **One argument** ...

  - ... of type **number**:

    ```
    var arr = new Array(4);
    ```

    Creates an *empty* array and sets its length to the number passed as argument. The array appears to have 4 elements (because its length is 4) but it does not contain any elements (e.g. `arr[0]` will be `undefined`).
  - ... **any other** type:

    ```
    var arr = new Array('foo');
    ```

    Creates an array containing one element, the argument passed to the constructor (the same as passing multiple arguments).

---

Because of this ambiguity of the `Array` constructor function, you should avoid it and use array literals instead:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

That said, to learn the basics, read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide), especially [about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Comment: Strange there is such a difference between [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) page and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) one.

Comment: Well, one is a reference and the other is a tutorial...

Comment: True... Normally only see the reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are  in learning curve. **[See here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)** You can write array items there.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array (Need editorial review)

Comment: however http://w3fools.com/ - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is normally a much better resource - in this case w3schools seems to be fairly ok

Comment: hence I also the tutorial which was also posted by Felix

Answer (score 0):

[Syntax Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[element0, element1, ..., elementN]
new Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN)
new Array(arrayLength)

[MDN Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object)